# We can cause "reactions on someone" or "reactions in someone"?

Tags: word-choice

Sometimes it's not clear to me when to use one or another, so can anyone help me?

We can cause "reactions on someone" or "reactions in someone"?

Like in this phrase: The judge set aside the case about the lake pollution and ordered a new trial for the next month, causing strong reactions in environmental actvists.

Comment: You don't do either. You elicit or prompt a reaction from them. You only cause a reaction in a test tube.

Comment: @RegDwigнt my reaction to your remark is that you err in proposing such a limited view of the word. See https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/reaction

Comment: I don't find *causing strong reactions in environmental activists* remotely idiomatic, but that's really because it features a number of different "imperfect" elements (any one of which might not even be *noticed*, on its own). It's usually singular ***a strong reaction*** (more often ***provoked*** than ***caused***) ***among*** (not ***in*** or ***on***, the latter of which is syntactically invalid) environmental activists.

Answer (score 1):

The difference depends on "*in*", pertaining to those things that lie inside some conceptual or physical boundary to a thing, and "*on*", pertaining to those things that are on or put on the exterior of the boundary (and may possibly then be transmitted onwards into the body of the thing). Let us consider the *judge* and the *group* as the two relevant "*things*".

The judge acts (has an effect) *on* the group by letting them know of her judgement; the group gets excited internally when it thinks about the judgement; their reactions to it come from within the group. They may react by shouting "Boo to the judge!". So their reaction *on* the judge is to shout and boo. She hears this on her exterior; whether there is any reaction within her is not known from the sentences.

The judge's judgement acts (externally heard or read) *on* the group and stimulates reactions (lots of animated discussion and calls for a response) in the group. The group then reacts *on* the judge. Consequently we say that the judgement caused reactions *in* the group and that the group reacted *on* the judge.

{I apologise if I seem to have laboured this.}

Comment: There are no hits at all in Google Books for ["reacted on the judge"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22reacted+on+the+judge%22) (or ["reacted **on** the **judgement**"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22reacted+on+the+judgement%22)), But there will be an awful lot for both those sequences with ***to*** rather than ***on***. You ***act on*** a stimulus, or you ***react to*** it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Perhaps so, but why look for such a restrictive phrase? The essence is in the use of the prepositions. I had checked that ngram shows a steady use of "*react on*". The choice of *judge* as the object is merely exemplary and appropriate to the question as posed.

Comment: I didn't *look* for "such a restrictive phrase". Your answer text includes the sentence "The group then reacts *on* the judge", where I maintain that the highlighted preposition ***on*** there isn't idiomatic - and I'd say I *proved* that by pointing out that there are no written instances at all involving judges or judgements with ***on***, even though there will be thousands with ***react to** [the judge, judgement, or whatever]*. Incidentally, I've no idea why, but the specific 2-word collocation ***react on*** has been undergoing a massive decline in popularity over the past century.

Comment: Well, there we are. "what's done, is done". Thanks

Comment: "The group reacted on the judge" is not English. And while "caused reactions in the group" is English, it is irrelevant to the question at hand, because there is no *group* in the question, only *activists*. You have replaced one word with another and answered the question for that different word. By that token, "I has beer" is perfectly grammatical, because you can simply replace *I* with *he*.

Comment: @RegDwigнt There is a group of activists. I use group in the first sense given in the online Cambridge dictionary: "a number of people or things that are put together or considered as a unit". Your assertion is at odds with the definition and, although dictionaries are not infallible, I see no reason to doubt this particular authority.

Comment: I think that what caused or provoked a strong reaction was the judge's decision. Do you think putting it in this way would be better?     "The judge set aside the case about the lake pollution ordering a new trial for the next month, a decision that provoked/caused strong reactions among environmental actvists."

Comment: It just needs a comma after *pollution* then it is OK.